# Implementing Automatic Syllable Splitting and Coloring in a Flutter App

Tags: flutter, text-processing

I'm currently working on an educational app in Flutter aimed at making reading easier for children. A key feature I want to add is automatic syllable splitting of texts. The idea is to have the app automatically divide texts into syllables and then display these syllables in alternating colors (e.g., red and blue) to facilitate reading. Can anyone provide tips or share experiences on how to program this in Flutter?

Thanks!

I'm at the initial stage and haven't tried any specific method for syllable splitting in my Flutter app yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it before but I found this [article](https://sarahsnippets.com/syllable-division-rules) which might help you with the basic logic and rules of Syllable Splitting. In my opinion & short research, technically it seems like it can be achieved with just basic if-else & looping to generate the resulting data.